# Get adjacent element in string

Tags: php

I am seeking to extract neighbor elements of a string in PHP for eg a string is like 11,12,13,14,15

If I pass neighbor(12) it should return 11 and 13. I am looking to do this without using explode for memory conservation (the example is a very small string) where as actual string will vary but will be separated by commas.

**Edit** IN case of first and last null should be returned for eg neighbor(15) before => 14 after => null

Comment: Have you tried something? (pseudo code, code, research)

Comment: explode -> array -> loop?

Comment: explode -> array_search -> prev/next or key +/- 1

Comment: `str_pos(',12,',...)` then move forwards_backups to the next commas and/or sos/eos.

Comment: yea, fixed... so close to quittin' time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/(?:(\d+),)?\b12\b(?:,(\d+))?/', $string, $match);
```

The neighbors will be in `$match[1]` and `$match[2]`.

Comment: Yeah it works... i want to ask some questions regarding regEx. Where regEx can be usefull. It look like tough to create. From where we can learn to create regEx.

Comment: There's a tutorial at regular-expression.info